# Delete previous image from folder when updated by new image

Tags: laravel-5

How can i delete the previous image from folder when it is update by new image.

in the code that I made it only added a new image in the image folder, and the previous image was not deleted.

this is my Controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $image_name = $request->hidden_image;
    $image      = $request->file('image');
    if ($image != '')
     {
      $request->validate(['judul' => 'required',
        'image' => 'image|max:2048'
    ]);
    $image_name = rand() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $image->move(public_path('uploadberita'), $image_name); 
     }
     else{
        $request->validate([
            'judul' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required',
            'artikel' => 'required'
        ]);
     }
     $form_data  = array(
            'judul' => $request->judul,
            'image' => $image_name,
            'artikel' => $request->artikel 
        );

     Berita::whereId($id)->update($form_data);
     return redirect()->route('admin.berita.index')->with('pesan', 'Data is Successfully update');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find record with image name

```
$row = Berita::whereId($id);
```

then remove using Storage facade

```
Storage::delete($row->image);
```

Laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/filesystem#deleting-files

Whole code will be like this

```
function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $image_name = $request->hidden_image;
    $image = $request->file('image');
    if ($image != '') {
        $request->validate([
            'judul' => 'required',
            'image' => 'image|max:2048'
        ]);
        $image_name = rand() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $image->move(public_path('uploadberita'), $image_name);
    } else {
        $request->validate([
            'judul' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required',
            'artikel' => 'required'
        ]);
    }
    $form_data = array(
        'judul' => $request->judul,
        'image' => $image_name,
        'artikel' => $request->artikel
    );

    $row = Berita::whereId($id)->first(); // <- find row with image name
    Storage::disk('public')->delete($row->image); // <- delete old image (do not forget import Storage facade)
    $row->update($form_data);

    return redirect()->route('admin.berita.index')->with('pesan', 'Data is Successfully update');
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but after I added the code, there was an error "Property [image] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance" . what should I fix again?

Comment: This is probably because you are not using `image` as field name on your table. Change your code fixing this field name and it will be ok.

Comment: but name of the field in my table is image

Comment: I edited the code suggested fixing the way to find the record. When using `whereId($id)` you get an eloquent builder instead of a model, which is returned when use `find($id)`